# Struts 2 richtextTinymceEditor is not working in Icanhaz.js tempale

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have used this normal jsp it is working fine , when add it in icnahaz template it is not render properly

```
<script id="publishactivity" type="text/html">

    <h3><s:property value='%{getText(\'profile.section.activity.title\')}'/></h3>
    <div id="id-publication-validations"></div>
    <s:form id="update-form" namespace="/test" action="test_publish" method="post">
        <s:hidden key="userForm.idUser"></s:hidden>
        <fieldset>
            <textarea name="text" id="update" class="new-publication" placeholder=""></textarea>
            <sjr:tinymce
                    id="richtextTinymceEditor"
                    name="echo"
                    rows="10"
                    cols="80"
                    width="800"
                    editorTheme="simple"
                    value="Cras dictum."
            />
            <div class="form-foot">
                <div class="form-commit">
                    <button type="button" id="id-button-publication" class="btn m b"><span class="in-btn"><s:property value='%{getText(\'profile.section.activity.button\')}'/></span></button>
                    <a id="id-new-publication"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </s:form>
```

Comment: I'm assuming the question is "how can I get it to work", right? What's in your JS console? How does the renovating system work? Are JSP tags evaluated in them?

Comment: yes , i have used other struts tag like <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> and these are working in same scenario but <%@ taglib prefix="sjr" uri="/struts-jquery-richtext-tags" %> is not working

Comment: Then you'll need to provide more information; there is nothing here which can be used to diagnose the problem.

Comment: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error]  
$(function() {  . i am getting this error in console.It is properly working on normal jsp page when i did not use this template

Comment: Apparently jQuery isn't getting loaded.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery from CDN behind a blocking proxy ?

Comment: no , i am testing it on my local pc

Comment: I understand my problem but not able to get solution.